# Eclipse source out of sync with file system

Tags: java, eclipse

I inherited a java project and don't have much experience with Eclipse. In the package explorer I can see the outline of the project with all the classes but when I try to edit any of them it says the source code is not found. When I look the source code is where it seems it is supposed to be. I am assuming that in pulling the code out of source control the path must have changed from the original. Is there an easy way to tell the IDE to just connect a code file to a class?

What's really weird is that 'some' of the files in the very same directory are found while others are not. Can't say I think very highly of this IDE so far.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing from within Eclipse? Right click on the project in the Package Explorer view and select Refresh.

Comment: Ah, now I can edit the source files! Thanks. It still shows the little warning signs next to the treeview items.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eclipse+resource+is+out+of+sync+with+filesystem

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Right click on the project in the Package Explorer view and select Refresh.

Comment: Well, this is not working. I'm trying to debug my Android project and all files other than the ones on my project are out of sync

Comment: This worked for me.. I didn't expect that it would be simple as this.

Comment: I had to refresh all open & related projects then it worked for me.

Comment: If this still doesn't do the trick, delete the error from the Markers view, than Clean and Refresh the project to see if the error comes up again.

Comment: I refreshed all open projects, then it worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

You can have Eclipse do that automatically for you.

Using the latest version, go to Window -> Preferences.

Select General -> Workspace and from there make sure the first and second option are checked:

- Build automatically
- Refresh using native hooks or polling

[image: Eclipse Workspace preferences]

This is very useful especially if you use Dropbox or something similar (wuala etc) :)

Answer (score 1):

just refreshing isnt *always* the answer. I had this source issue happen when I had imported two projects with the same context for review and Eclipse made me disambiguate them, forcing a change to the web context of the second. The source for one was linking to the other context's source folder. eg

- project A(in folder A1) deployed as /A
- project A(in folder A2)
  deployed as /A also but was forced to be /A[later**] upon import

in `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` (within folder A1) the `wb-module` element referred to the other context /A[later] and was using its source code, not that for /A.

I solved this by updating all references in the `org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file in each project to suit their correct project

** *the suffix I chose upon import, it has no particular significance*

Answer (score 0):

By default, 'F5' on a highlighted resource will also refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the project name and click refresh. And just to be sure, you can select the package name and right click 'Refresh' too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project in the Package Explorer view and select Refresh. If it is not working,
2. Clean the project... project menu -> clean... and refresh

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project, then press F5 to refresh the file. It should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If refresh and clean doesn't work, it might work to just simply just run your code. For me it did the trick. After many refresh and cleaning/ building didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove all projects from eclipse workspace and Re-Import the all projects again. It is working for me. Just try it

Answer (score 0):

If using maven or other builder be sure that you disable the plug ins some plug ins, specially the ones meant to generate/change code will never let you be fully on sync