# Error in packaging executable jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, packaging, executable-jar

I have a Java code that can run correctly in eclipse.

[image]
[image]

I need to run this java program outside eclipse, so I tried to export it as executable jar file.

[image]

I have one warning poped up:
[image]

Then, I have JAR creating failed error with `Resource is out of sync` message.

[image]

What might be wrong? What's the command to execute the java program outside the eclipse?

### ADDED

Googling ( [Eclipse source out of sync with file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626703/eclipse-source-out-of-sync-with-file-system) ) to remove the `resource is out of sync` error, but I have many `duplicate errors`.

[image]

Why do I have these errors? How can I remove them? I downloaded the project from mercurial repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could generate the executable jar, this is the summary that I had to do in order to make it work.

### Removing the duplicate file.

I found some error messages saying that there are duplicate files. I couldn't understand why eclipse thinks there are duplicate files, but by removing the files, I could remove the errors.

### Excluding some of the files

In Build -> Configure Build Path 
[image]

I had to remove or exclude source folders.

[image]

### Always sync by refreshing

I had to use F5 key to refresh the build, or I could do that automatically using eclipse setup : [image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a situation like: Project A is referring to B & C. C is also referring to B and you are trying to create a runnable jar for A?

This was causing the problem for me. I some how managed to remove the dependency of C in A and that helped!