# Eclipse "Resource of of sync with file system" - Refresh doesn't fix

Tags: eclipse

When I do a file search in Eclipse I get an error saying "Resource of of sync with file system"

> '/RemoteControl/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/RemoteControl/.indexes/properties.index'.').
>   Resource is out of sync with the file system:
>   '/RemoteControl/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/RemoteControl/.indexes/properties.index'.

This problem is treated extensively in this Stack Overflow question:
[avoiding "resource is out of sync with the filesystem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343735/avoiding-resource-is-out-of-sync-with-the-filesystem)
...but the basic remedy they discuss involve **refreshing** the project, and the discussion revolves around the best way to do it; whether to do it automatically, the side-effects of refreshing, etc.

Refresh is also the preferred solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626703/eclipse-source-out-of-sync-with-file-system) Stack Overflow question

But I get the error even if I **immediately** precede the search with a manual refresh (right click on my project - Refresh).   So I don't think that's it.  So what else could cause this error?

**BTW**, the file search does seem to successfully find all my source (java, xml) files so this doesn't seem to be preventing me from working but I don't know what its other implications are.

Comment: The paths here look a bit odd. Do you have a workspace called 'RemoteControl' containing a project with the same name?

Comment: Is the workspace located on a network share? That can cause mysterious problems like this.

Comment: @greg-449  The top of my Package Explorer says RemoteControl and then next to it in square brackets RemoteControl.    So if the first one is the workspace name and the second is the project name, then yes.   Is that a problem?    BTW my file search **does** seem to successfully find all my source files.  I'll edit my question to make that clear.

Comment: @nitind.  No, it's not on a network share.  Everything is on my C: drive.